# UWP (C#) - View files in LocalFolder

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app

How can I view file created via `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("...")` operation?

I remember Windows Phone Power Tools back in Windows Phone 8 days but is there any way to do this today?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On desktop, you can go to your app's folder directly as RicardoPons proposed, as for mobile - I belive [Windows Phone IsoStoreSpy](https://isostorespy.codeplex.com/) tool still works for Windows 10 Mobile.

Comment: Same as Power Tools the IsoStoreSpy supports only WP8 and WP8.1.

Comment: I'm literally sitting at my workplace right now and using it for UWP project. Give it a try.

Comment: OK, I will try it. :)

Answer (score 5):

you can go to the hidden folder example C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Packages\App.AppName.YourAppsGuid.AppName\LocalState 
or ...\RoamingState

Best regards

Comment: if this is useful for you please mark this as the answer! thank you!

Comment: Thank you for respond. I tried that but the directory was empty (the file should be there I believe). I will try that again...

Comment: Please remember this folder AppData is hidden. I checked in my own app and I can see my saved data only for desktop because for mobile is not supported